# Error IDX40001 Issuer does not match any of the valid issuers provided for this application

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

#### Edit

Looks like the problem is with `.NET 8` Blazor app.

I created a brand new Blazor Server project with this CLI command:
`dotnet new blazorserver -au IndividualB2C -o blazor.server.net7` which created my project in `net7.0`. I then hooked up my B2C to it and it all worked fine ✨.

[image]

But when I changed it to `.NET 8`, I ran into this error:
[image]

I then wanted to create a new `net8.0` project using a similar command to get the auth setup for me (`-au IndividualB2C`) but looks like it doesn't exist for .NET 8 yet:
[image]

Also Visual Studio Version 17.8.0 Preview 2.0 doesn't present any window to choose Authentication type.

[image]

So I created a new `net8.0` project using Rider (I'm on a Mac).
I added the necessary nuget packages and copied Auth setup from the `net7.0` project.
The issue persists.

---

#### Original Post

I've been trying to setup my .NET 8 Blazor Web App (Server side) to connect to Azure AD B2C to log in users and call a secured API.
I have pieced together instructions mostly from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app-with-api?tabs=visual-studio), [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/tree/main/WebApp-OIDC/B2C/blazorserver-B2C) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-8.0).

The web app launches, takes me to the login page and lets me enter my credentials:
[image]

After I hit "Sign In", it just keeps on spinning and spinning on this url:

```
https://munsonpickles3.b2clogin.com/munsonpickles3.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=171b3d8f-8ff1-48b7-a5be-31b0413929ee&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7032%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fmunsonpickles3.onmicrosoft.com%2Fmunson-api%2Fread&code_challenge=abcDe8FGl6jNrCyWPls56yaKjYuohGtD6vUpSgJe6nA&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=form_post&nonce=638123410660191340.YjRmNjYkOTOtN2IkNi00YzgxLTg0ZGEtMTRjNTIxZjcxOWJhMzYwZDk1ZDItOGIxNy00NTRiLThiMzgtOWM2MmVkZTlhYjc1&client_info=1&x-client-brkrver=IDWeb.2.14.0.0&state=CfDJ8L8UGyfUjDBErg6qYS34nXD3E0mLxkSA-InrXSkiEcmt8_eHquvuIC-GnidwO47o_SdGzL58675xXvBYP49rsnKjKti0bUUM1FvXyK5N7-AnYGdzo9SqoahAP5Ps7ykpi93LFX-Uis3xf068-S61dmuEn-8FmIKR3TOxzYJrKxAbG6dbymelCxbJ8xpESofmPRBQ9yKCi4flT8yTOFBtOszKtg2GTmxy9MMeX3edKDxpuTniV4YNXzzw-NpSL7DRHRLYSpbrOasGhk_dUrY0WWL3CY_43FmiKUSLiO60JheXpqYL_D53MA6nf0InABDhmkBNroqZgo7Qnv2hpgXSefZOLNgWkdcyTY8Pe-ZvCPX0ncBfkgqFFmQCNjXip-j0PnjRDLgHlldx70qi9ecSKdXgqvuW8a17QjrrEDAHUSCU&x-client-SKU=ID_NET8_0&x-client-ver=7.0.0.0
```

[image]

And ultimately ends up like this on the redirect url (notice the amount of cookies it tried to set which gets too long and runs into 431 error):
[image]

The console of my IDE shows this error:
`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: IDX40001: Issuer: 'https://munsonpickles3.b2clogin.com/f6c04159-d728-43cd-8ae1-c1f3793844d5/v2.0/', does not match any of the valid issuers provided for this application.`

I then checked all the config in my appsettings.json which seems to match what's in the App registration in my AADB2C directory.

```
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://munsonpickles3.b2clogin.com/",
    "Domain": "munsonpickles3.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "12345d8f-8ff1-48b7-a5be-31b041312345",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "12345~6MzNJ3yk.YTq9iP51R1niJFWuxaGx12345",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": ""
  }
```

[image]

The redirect urls are also set correctly:
[image]

I ran the flow by pointing the redirect url to `jwt.ms`, and looked at the Issuer which is the same one that the app is complaining about:
[image]

```
Issuer: 'https://munsonpickles3.b2clogin.com/f6c04159-d728-43cd-8ae1-c1f3793844d5/v2.0/', does not match any of the valid issuers provided for this application.
```

I have followed all the steps by going through all the docs I could find, but after spending 2 days on this, I think I need help.

#### Exceptions (if any)

```
fail: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
      IDX40001: Issuer: 'https://munsonpickles3.b2clogin.com/f6c04159-d728-43cd-8ae1-c1f3793844d5/v2.0/', does not match any of the valid issuers provided for this application. 
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[17]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: IDX40001: Issuer: 'https://munsonpickles3.b2clogin.com/f6c04159-d728-43cd-8ae1-c1f3793844d5/v2.0/', does not match any of the valid issuers provided for this application. 
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ValidateTokenUsingHandlerAsync(String idToken, AuthenticationProperties properties, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
```

#### Logs

Turned on PII logging as suggested by ΩmegaMan.
The logs read like this:

```
info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
      IDX10242: Security token: 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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' has a valid signature.
info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
      IDX10239: Lifetime of the token is valid.
info: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
      IDX10234: Audience Validated.Audience: '12345d8f-8ff1-48b7-a5be-31b041312345'
fail: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
      IDX40001: Issuer: 'https://munsonpickles3.b2clogin.com/f6c04159-d728-43cd-8ae1-c1f3793844d5/v2.0/', does not match any of the valid issuers provided for this application. 
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[17]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: IDX40001: Issuer: 'https://munsonpickles3.b2clogin.com/f6c04159-d728-43cd-8ae1-c1f3793844d5/v2.0/', does not match any of the valid issuers provided for this application. 
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ValidateTokenUsingHandlerAsync(String idToken, AuthenticationProperties properties, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
```

#### .NET Version

8.0.100-preview.7.23376.3

#### Anything else?

Also asked this in the [aspnetcore github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51005).

Comment: Mask your Credentials in AAD => App registartion and configuration file,Do not expose them.

Comment: @Harshitha Thank you. I have removed the first and last 5 characters with `12345`.

Comment: Could you please share your Redirect URI which you haev set in Screen shot.

Comment: Are you getting the issue locally or for the deployed app?

Comment: Hi Harshita, this is during local, haven't been able to make it work locally so deploying it is a distant thing.  Also added the url in the question. Take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I want to check the Authentication section which you have set.Please share the [image](https://i.imgur.com/9ft1ecV.png)

Comment: @Harshitha I added screenshot of the 'Authentication section' in the question. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255465/discussion-between-harshitha-and-ash-k).

Comment: You are following a doc for web app, Instead follow this link which has a [blazor configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: When you run the flow in B2C and direct it to jwt.io or jwt.ms, look at the issuer claim on the token. Does it match what you expect, or is it even being sent? You may want to specify `Identity Provider Access Token` as being sent down in the `Application Claims` section of the flow. Otherwise, create a new project and during that initial operation just register the app via the wizard for Microsoft Identity into B2C; to see if it has the same issue.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan I did what you suggested and documented the findings in the question. Can you please take a look again? Thanks!

Comment: You can try to turn on PII logging. It goes to the console window. `"EnablePiiLogging": true`

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Turned it on and copied the logs in the question. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: The first line of what you see vs what I see. My report looks like this: `IDX10242: Security token: '{"alg":"RS256","kid":"X5e...`. Have you tried creating a new project and letting the wizard do the app registration and place in the .net core startup service code? It seems like you may be doing something, as in `program.cs` which is different.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan I didn't let IDE or CLI do the app registration for me in .NET 8 because 1. I'm on a Mac and I don't have full fat Visual Studio (I'm using Rider) 2. There's no command for this in .NET 8 that I had for .NET 7 which is `dotnet new blazorserver -au IndividualB2C -o projectname`. Please let me know if you know a command that I can use for .NET 8. Also if you created a new project for .NET with `-au IndividualB2C` setup or through full fat Visual Studio, please share that to me through a Git repo and I'll grab it and test it. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255478/discussion-between-ash-k-and-megaman).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this resolved or not but there was it seems a bug in the NuGet packages and an update should resolve it. See: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/discussions/2481